# How to import LXC containers from a previously used ZFS lxc zpool?

Tags: lxc

I'm using all default lxc settings with ZFS as the backstore.

Which means, I have an lxc zpool and created containers with `lxc-create -B zfs -n ubuntu-base -t ubuntu`

Now, the root fs ran out of space because I was testing lxc with ZFS and a zpool created from a file.

I attached a virtual drive to the VM `/dev/sdb`, exported the exiting lxc zpool, and created a new lxc zpool with `/dev/sdb`

Then, imported the old lxc zpool as `lxc-old`
Then, used `zfs send` all datasets from `lxc-old` to `lxc`, destroyed `lxc-old`

Now `lxc-ls -f` no longer shows any existing containers, but zfs shows the datasets

`root@lxc:~# lxc-ls -f
root@lxc:~#`

`root@lxc:~# zfs list
NAME                       USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
lxc                       5.40G  45.1G    19K  /lxc
lxc/clamav                 679M  45.1G   870M  /var/lib/lxc/clamav/rootfs
lxc/hadoop                 541M  45.1G   710M  /var/lib/lxc/hadoop/rootfs
lxc/hulk                  1.11G  45.1G  1.26G  /var/lib/lxc/hulk/rootfs
lxc/mongodb               1.03G  45.1G  1.16G  /var/lib/lxc/mongodb/rootfs
lxc/mongodb2              1.03G  45.1G  1.16G  /var/lib/lxc/mongodb/rootfs
lxc/python                48.2M  45.1G   185M  /var/lib/lxc/python/rootfs
lxc/slamdata               427M  45.1G   576M  /var/lib/lxc/slamdata/rootfs
lxc/splunk                 172M  45.1G   324M  /var/lib/lxc/splunk/rootfs
lxc/ubuntu-base            229M  45.1G   210M  /var/lib/lxc/ubuntu-base/rootfs
lxc/ubuntu-base@python       1K      -   151M  -
lxc/ubuntu-base@mongodb      1K      -   151M  -
lxc/ubuntu-base@slamdata     1K      -   151M  -
lxc/ubuntu-base@hulk         1K      -   151M  -
lxc/ubuntu-base@splunk       1K      -   151M  -
lxc/ubuntu-base@hadoop    17.0M      -   187M  -
lxc/ubuntu-base@new          1K      -   210M  -
lxc/ubuntu-base@clamav       1K      -   210M  -`

I'm not exactly sure how to get lxc to see the existing containers in the new lxc zpool

Comment: I think I know why now. They are missing `config` file in their respective containers. Will have to test it out

Answer (score 1):

The reason I "lost" all of my containers was what I had previously suspected, the `config` file being missing.

When ZFS is used as the backstore, and a new container is created, such as `/var/lib/lxc/clamav/rootfs`, only the rootfs directory is contained in the backstore (ZFS)

The `config` file is stored in the path `/var/lib/lxc/<container>/config`, which isn't stored in the backstore.

The solution is to create a dataset with a mountpoint of `/var/lib/lxc/`

`root@lxc:~# zfs list
NAME                                      USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
lxc                                      11.4G  37.5G   526M  /lxc
lxc/_configs                               44K  37.5G    44K  /var/lib/lxc/
lxc/_share                                252K  37.5G   252K  /usr/share/lxc/`

Problem solved.

Comment: Interesting. I've manually migrated my LXC containers to ZFS, and set my mountpoint for lxc to /var/lib/lxc, which includes all the configs. The rootfs for each LXC is in its own dataset like LXC expects with the ZFS backend. Glad to hear you solved the issue!

Comment: @fideli I had created the containers without first setting the mountpoints (because I just didn't know), so when I migrated it I lost all the configs :/

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a bit of a shot in the dark, but try the following. I noticed that in your `zfs list` you have the following:

```
NAME                       USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
lxc                       5.40G  45.1G    19K  /lxc
...
```

Perhaps your new lxc dataset needs to be mounted to `/var/lib/lxc`.

```
zfs set mountpoint=/var/lib/lxc lxc
```

Comment: By default `/var/lib/lxc` is the location for new privileged containers. BY specifying the backstore as ZFS it will create a new container as a dataset in a zpool named 'lxc' and set its mountpoint to the base directory of `/var/lib/lxc`